# Cookie php codeigniter

Tags: php, cookie, codeigniter

Есть форма , после отправки - страница перезагружается, post-ом записываю в переменную и отображаю. Далее записываю в куки и отображается куки. Не подскажите, как можно отправить форму и отобразить сразу куки и пост ? получается после перезагрузки появляется пост, потом нужно ещё один раз перезагрузить для кукиса.

```
        <form class="login" method="POST"  >
            <div class="row">
                <label for="login">Логин</label>
                <input type="text" id="login" name="login">
            </div>
            <input type="submit" value="Войти">         
        </form>
        <?= $value = $_POST['login']; 
        setcookie("Cookie", $value);
        ?>
        <? echo $_COOKIE["Cookie"]; ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CodeIgniter 4

```
helper('cookie');
return redirect()->route('home')->setCookie('name', 'value', time() + 86400);
```

Или

```
helper('cookie');
set_cookie('name', 'value', time() + 86400);
return redirect()->to('/home');
```

Вывод

```
get_cookie('name');
```